# Error with loading json files when opening main page

Tags: javascript, jhipster

I am using Jhipster, and when I open my browser and go on the main page of my website (localhost:8080), I always have these errors :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/i18n/en/global.json Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   2http://localhost:8080/i18n/en/language.json Failed to load resource:
>   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:8080/i18n/en/global.json

If I reload the page the problem doesn't occur anymore.
I don't know if it's related to Jhipster or if it's due to something else.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide details: jhipster version, browser and OS.

Comment: It was my falt, I made a mistake in my code. Nothing to do with Jhipster.